# angularjs calling controller functions while application load

Tags: angularjs

I have a $promise service in controller and i want to call these services while application start.

```
 CustomerService.fetchReligion.list().$promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.religionList = response; 
      $window.localStorage.setItem('religionList', JSON.stringify(response));                                                      
   }, function(error) {
      // error handler
  });     
  CustomerService.fetchCaste.list().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.casteList = response;  
    $window.localStorage.setItem('casteList', JSON.stringify(response));                                                                               
    }, function(error) {
     // error handler
  });
```

How do i call these services?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you share what you're trying to accomplish and the code that you've tried?

Comment: i am storing  the return JSON values in the local storage for later use.

Comment: You can use `ng-init="yourControllerFn()"` to execute a function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). UI-Router has a ["Resolve" functionality](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) in which, whenever the view changes to a particular state, promises shall be resolved and made into a value before the corresponding controller is instantiated. This means that whenever the new state/view (and its controller) is loaded, it is ensured that the required objects/values have already been retrieved and are ready for use.

The following snippet is directly taken from UI-Router's documentation.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  resolve:{

     ...

     // Example using function with returned promise.
     // This is the typical use case of resolve.
     // You need to inject any services that you are
     // using, e.g. $http in this example
     promiseObj:  function($http){
        // $http returns a promise for the url data
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
     },

     // Another promise example. If you need to do some 
     // processing of the result, use .then, and your 
     // promise is chained in for free. This is another
     // typical use case of resolve.
     promiseObj2:  function($http){
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'})
           .then (function (data) {
               return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
           });
     },        

     ...

  // The controller waits for every one of the above items to be
  // completely resolved before instantiation. For example, the
  // controller will not instantiate until promiseObj's promise has 
  // been resolved. Then those objects are injected into the controller
  // and available for use.  
  controller: function($scope, simpleObj, promiseObj, promiseObj2, translations, translations2, greeting){

      ...

      // You can be sure that promiseObj is ready to use!
      $scope.items = promiseObj.data.items;
      $scope.items = promiseObj2.items;

      ...
  }
})
```